# How do I achieve queryaccelearation=all and packageset using Java JDBC?

Tags: java, db2

i am setting the queryaccelearation=all in below code and i am getting the below exception.

//set queryacceleration
                      String url = "host:60010/DB2:user=xxxx;password=yyyyy;specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL;";

```
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props); - ERROR:  com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10214][10050][3.62.56] java.util.Properties object passed to java.sql.Driver.connect() cannot be overridden by URL: jdbc:db2://ddcs.example.com:50010/DB2T:user=xxxxx;password=yyyyy;specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL;. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Thanks,
Rasheed SK

Comment: Which part of the error message seems unclear?

Answer (score 0):

1. java.util.Properties object passed to java.sql.Driver.connect() cannot be overridden by URL

You must not specify user and password twice - in the URL and in the properties. Exclude them from either place.

2. Current package set cat be specified in the URL like this:

   jdbc:db2://50010/DB2T:specialRegisters=CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL;currentPackageSet=F9DERWSl;

Comment: when i running my code CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL is not working, but package set  is working fine.

Comment: is any alternative solution there setup for CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL

Comment: Edit your question to specify the (new) exception details.