# How to set set current query acceleration=ALL in java jdbc application?

Tags: db2

when i set the below code current query acceleration=ALL it's not working for me but package set was worked.

> jdbc:db2://:50010/DB2T:specialRegisters=CURRENT
>   QUERY ACCELERATION=ALL;currentPackageSet=F9DERWSl;

is any alternative solution will be there for set current query acceleration=ALL?
could you please help for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I achieve queryaccelearation=all and packageset using Java JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202192/how-do-i-achieve-queryaccelearation-all-and-packageset-using-java-jdbc)

Comment: while i am setting current query acceleration=all , i didn't find any exception but it's connecting db2 data base not idaa.

Comment: Better to Edit your question to add new information, not write in comments. Are queries that are eligible for acceleration returning result-sets?

Comment: yes it's elgible.